# jOOQ requires Timestamp type to access datetime type in MySQL but this doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp, jooq

I have a MySQL database with data like this:

[image: mysql date data example]

These dates have data types **datetime**:

[image: mysql data types]

We are using jOOQ in our project for querying MySQL. Now I need to exclude all entries older than a particular date from a result set. jOOQ demands to set a **Timestamp** value, and when I do it doesn't impact the result set at all:

```
@Override
public Map<Timestamp, Integer> getCountOfAddedXXXwithoutBlabla6SinceDate() {
    Field<Timestamp> dateField = field(name("date"), Timestamp.class);
    Field<Integer> countField = field(name("count"), Integer.class);
    return db.selectDistinct(XXX.CREATED.as("date"), count(XXX.CREATED).as("count"))
            .from(XXX).where(XXX.ID.notIn(db.select(XXX.ID)
                    .from(XXX.join(XXXYYY).on(XXXYYY.XXX.eq(XXX.ID)))
                    .where(XXXYYY.BLABLA.eq(6)))
                    .and(XXX.CREATED.ge(
                            new Timestamp(1396310400)))) //1st of April, 2014
            .groupBy(XXX.CREATED)
            .fetchMap(dateField, countField);
}
```

This query effectively escapes all Blabla6 results but ignores the `greaterOrEqual(new Timestamp())` condition. *Maybe because MySQL does not convert timestamp into datetime automatically?*

However, this query does exactly what I need:

```
@Override
public Map<Timestamp, Integer> getCountOfAddedXXXwithoutBlabla6SinceDate() {
    Field<Timestamp> dateField = field(name("date"), Timestamp.class);
    Field<Integer> countField = field(name("count"), Integer.class);
    return db.selectDistinct(XXX.CREATED.as("date"), count(XXX.CREATED).as("count"))
            .from(XXX).where(XXX.ID.notIn(db.select(XXX.ID)
                    .from(XXX.join(XXXYYY).on(XXXYYY.XXX.eq(XXX.ID)))
                    .where(XXXYYY.BLABLA.eq(6)))
                    .and(XXX.CREATED.ge(
                            select(ZZZ.START).from(ZZZ)
                                    .where(ZZZ.ID.eq(44818))))) //44818 is ZZZ Id that started on 1st of April, 2014, ZZZ.START is of datetime type
            .groupBy(XXX.CREATED)
            .fetchMap(dateField, countField);
}
```

This effectively skips results older than 1st of April 2014 and excludes Blabla6 belongings. *But this makes the code dependent on the particular database value, which is totally unacceptable.* jOOQ requires Timestamp type in its `ge()` method in the query! How can I set a point in time with jOOQ to make my MySQL **datetime**-type column recognize them?

Comment: show your result sql query that JOOQ generates

Comment: What do you mean by "ignores the condition"? It certainly doesn't ignore it, but perhaps it doesn't work as you expected? Can you please provide the DEBUG output when running the query? See: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging

Comment: @Nikolay when I use the **Timestamp 1396310400** the first lines of the result are: `Returned Dates: 2014-02-18 00:00:00.0 Returned count values: 3;
Returned Dates: 2014-02-19 00:00:00.0 Returned count values: 5;
Returned Dates: 2014-02-26 00:00:00.0 Returned count values: 1;`
which is NOT correct (start too early). When I use an existing **datetime** value, first lines of the result set are correct, starts with: `Returned Dates: 2014-04-01 00:00:00.0 Returned count values: 2;
Returned Dates: 2014-04-04 00:00:00.0 Returned count values: 2;'

Comment: @LukasEder, you are right, not like expected. Sorry for the word misuse. Sorry for my noob-ness again, I don't understand this: *In order to see any DEBUG log output, put either log4j or slf4j on jOOQ's classpath along with their respective configuration.*
I have made a log4j config like:
`log4j.appender.jooq=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.jooq.File=logs/jooq.log
log4j.appender.jooq.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jooq.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.logger.jooq = TRACE, jooq`
What should I do now? (We use *org.apache.log4j.Logger*)

Comment: @Nikolay, sorry, I just got what you mean - the query that jooq generates. Can I see it in jOOQ's DEBUG logger? Because I'm trying to find out how to see it.